# Expand and Collapse View in Window phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, expression-blend, windows-phone-7.1

On a page of my wiondows phone7 app, I have to display a list of Employee Names which are coming from the server in XML format.

what i need is when i click the name of any employee, it should expand to display the details of that employee and other eployee name name should slide down.

For example

**First Screen**

Mohit Leekha

Kushal Khera

Kashish narula

whaen i click on **Mohit Leekha** the screen should Look Like

Mohit Leekha

      Male    22

      Employee Id

      Display Picture  etc

Kushal Khera

Kashish Narula

How can i implement it.

The only thing i can think of now is to alter the visibility of the content.

Is there any control available for this.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the ExpanderView in the Silverlight for Windows Phone toolkit:
http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/71550

Comment: i found this toolkit is available for 7.1 and 7.5 but not for 7.0, correct me if i am wrong and provide me the link from where i can download it for 7.0

Comment: ExpanderView is only available in the mango toolkit (Aug. 2011)

Answer (score 1):

If you add the employees to a ListBox then you can set the ItemTemplate to anything you want. You could then use an existing expandable control (e.g. ExpanderView from the WP7 toolkit) or create your own.

```
<ListBox ...>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <toolkit:ExpanderView>
                ....
            </toolkit:ExpanderView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```